# Is it possible to create dummy account in paypal

Tags: paypal

I am a developer, I just want to test the features that are available in `Paypal iOS SDK`. I don't have PayPal account with me. During [signup](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/merchantboarding/webflow/unifiedflow?execution=e1s2) they will ask for the business details,I don't have any business details to fill.  My doubt is can I create a dummy account in Paypal just to test the SDK by giving dummy values for business details.

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Follow this steps: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/ipn-test-outside

**EDIT:**

Follow this additional steps to create a bussiness test account:

https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_testing_sandbox_get_started#business

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in that link they have mentioned to create the business account with bank detail, I am bit confused please help me.

Comment: I think you can enter dummy bussiness details to test, and change them later when you mean real bussiness.

Comment: However, here it is specified how to create a bussiness TEST account: https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_testing_sandbox_get_started#business

Answer (score 1):

Try paypal sandbox
Check the blow link

[https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts][1]